# Adjusting font size to fit component height

Tags: user-interface, javafx, text, fonts

I am currently resizing a button in javafx using the code snippet below.

```
public class ResizableEventButton extends Button {

    public ResizableEventButton(String label, EventHandler<ActionEvent> event) {
        super(label);
        setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
        setOnAction(event);
        widthProperty().addListener((observable -> {
            Text text = new Text(getText());
            text.setFont(getFont());
            double oldSize = getFont().getSize();
            double newSize = oldSize * getWidth() / text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
            setFont(Font.font(getFont().getFamily(), newSize));
        }));
    }
}
```

This works, but when the button is asked by the layout manager to resize, the text prevents this from happening.

For example (layout constraints expect the components to share the space 70%/30%):

[Buttons used in a MigPane and not conforming to layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYDGI.png)

[Standard panes used in the same MigPane, conforming to the layout constraints.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDOh2.png)

Can anyone suggest how I can also resize the font to maximise text size without making the button violate vertical size constraints?

Thanks

Comment: Provide a [mcve] to replicate behavior.  Try to stick to standard JavaFX panes to demonstrate the issue rather than third party things like MigPane.

Comment: Perhaps this should better be done via a custom skin which overrides a method like [layoutLabelInArea](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/fc3792d5cb39cd3706f28953c3f97bdecc07bba6/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/LabeledSkinBase.java#L478), though I don't have any specifics on how you would accomplish what you want using such a method.  The current method will clip overflow text (or perhaps use the ellipsis), perhaps you could override to set a desired font size instead.

Comment: Another alternative is to put the button in a group, and scale the group as appropriate.

Comment: Do you really need the font to change size like this?

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for giving a variety of suggestions, do you know if there is a way to make the button height not bound to the size of the text? aka if the text is too big then it will get cut/not drawn. if this is the case i would be able to select an appropriate fontscale whenever the button is resized.

Comment: Study the [tips for sizing and aligning nodes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/size_align.htm#JFXLY133). `button.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE)`, also set min height to 0, might help but it resizes the button, not the font.  Font sizes are fixed for layout as described in the linked article.